# Heart Sound Samples

Tags: cardiology, heartbeat

Does anybody have helpful sources/links that are basically recordings and playbacks of heart sounds (normal/ abnormal/ etc.) that I could just listen to while in my spare time? I am looking for something outside of Youtube.
Thanks

Comment: Can you rephrase the title into a question? Like "Where can I find audio samples of Heart Sounds?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a free selection [here](https://archive.org/details/0056-0000-8039-0000-0-0000-0000-0).

It covers:

1. The normal heart
2. Interventricular septal defect
3. Interatrial septal defect
4. Pulmonary stenosis
5. Patent ductus arteriosus
6. Mitral stenosis
7. Mitral insufficiency
8. Aortic stenosis
9. Aortic insufficiency
10. Hypertension within the systemic circulation
11. Hypertension within the pulmonary circulation
12. Gallop rhythm
13. Sclerosis of the aorta
14. Pericarditis.